# Classic CoreData error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm getting this classic error :

*The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store*

This is how it's implemented :

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 

 NSManagedObject *newShot = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"shotName" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSString *newName= @"test"; 
 [newShot setName:newName];
```

And this is how it's designed :

[image]
[image]

No only I'm getting a crash with the message above, I'm also getting this warning :

*'NSManagedObject' may not respond to '-setName:'*

Obviously something is wrong somewhere, I think I'm using Strings on both side though .

---

Edit, I'm now using this after Eimantas's comment :

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
 NSManagedObject *newShot = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"shotName" inManagedObjectContext:context];
 NSString *newName= @"test"; 
 [newShot setValue:newName forKey:@"shotNumber"]; 
 [context saveAction];
```

But I`m still getting :

'NSManagedObjectContext' may not respond to '-saveAction'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setValue:forKey:`

**UPDATE**

`NSManagedObjectContext` has `save` method, not `saveAction`. So:

```
NSError *error = nil;
[context save:&error]
if (error) {
  [NSApp presentError:error];
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, still getting an error though ( edited the question )

Comment: hmm, something might be fishy here , I'm still getting :  'NSManagedObjectContext' may not respond to '-save'

Comment: try logging the context variable. Maybe it's something else?

Comment: The context variable seems to be logging ok : <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x5b5bd70>

Comment: but I'm crashing with this message :'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObjectContext saveAction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b5bd70'

Comment: you still have your `saveAction` somewhere? On a button maybe?

Comment: yep, same thing using "save" alone : 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObjectContext save]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5bc27e0'

Comment: save method needs an argument (NSError object) hence selector becomes save: (note the colon).

Answer (score 1):

`insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"shotName"` must be `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Shots"`. `Shots` is the entity name. `shotName` is the name of an attribute of the entity `Shots`. Also, like with Objective-C class names, it's standard to use singular names for your entity objects. So, `Shots` should be be `Shot` (recommended, but not required).

Also, if you change around your `AppName.xcdatamodel` file & generate new `NSManagedObject` files, you may also get the error: *The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store* upon app launch. It's because it's using the old persistent store file. I call it: `AppName.sqlite`, but you may have a different name for this file. Search in your project for something like:

```
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"AppName.sqlite"]];
```

Then, once you know the name, to find the file, do:

```
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/ -name AppName.sqlite
```

Then, remove the file, and build & run again.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at the code the first time. Just the error. I read the code this time, and I think I found the solution. I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for that, that wasn`t the only things preventing it to work :)